# Characteristic polynomial of binary matrix over the field F2 or GF(2)

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

How can the characteristic polynomial of a binary matrix (one with only zeros and ones) be found programmatically, where the process operates in the finite field F<sub>2</sub> (also known as GF(2)) and the coefficients are zeros and ones?

Here's what I have tried:

1. SymPy's `charpoly()` method doesn't give the answer I want, since it doesn't operate on the field F<sub>2</sub> and gives a polynomial with coefficients well beyond 0 and 1. However, is it possible to adapt the output of `charpoly()` to return the characteristic polynomial over F<sub>2</sub>, or to have the `charpoly()` method operate on that field?
2. [This repository](https://github.com/jamiecounsell/Berkowitz) is about the most convenient thing I could find that could solve this question. As of this writing I am trying it out now. However, it is very slow (is on track to take many hours) for the sizes of matrices I am interested in (128x128 to 256x256). Moreover, I had to modify the source code to fit my needs since the code, as is, doesn't take arbitrary matrices.

I am asking this question because finding the characteristic polynomial in F<sub>2</sub> is part of the process of calculating the appropriate jump parameter for certain random number generators (see my [note on this](https://github.com/peteroupc/peteroupc.github.io/blob/master/jump.md)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial returned by `charpoly()` can be adapted for the GF(2) finite field, and it's easy to do: odd coefficients become ones, and even coefficients become zeros. And this is enough for my purposes. Therefore, my issue is solved.

Comment: I wonder if the current proposal for DomainMatrix might help (https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/18844).